# How do I concatenate the results from multiple join tables into a delimmited list using a single mySql query?

Tags: mysql, select, join, concatenation

In MySql, I have a documents table, a folders table, and a searchtags table

```
Documents
  ID
  title

Folders
  ID
  title

Searchtags
  ID
  title

docFolders
  docID -> Documents.ID
  folderID -> Folders.ID

docSearchtags
  docID -> Documents.ID
  searchtagID -> Searchtags.ID
```

In the above, docFolders and docSearchtags are many-to-many join tables expressing the relationship between documents and folders, and documents and searchtags.  A single document can have multiple folders and multiple searchtags associated with it.

I am wondering if it is possible to create a *single* query that will SELECT the title of all documents, as well as a delimmited list of every folder title that belongs to a each document, and also a delimmited list of every searchtag title that belongs to each document.

For example, the resultset might look something like this:

```
RESULT
docTitle                  | folderTitles           | searchtagTitles 
The Quick Brown Fox       | foxes, colours         | Bushy tails, browny, foxy
The Slow Green Turtle     | turtles, colours       | Hard shells, slimy, turtle-soup
The Cute Fluffy Bunny     | bunnies, cute          | Fluffy, rabbit, rabbit-stew
```

Thanks (in advance) for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT d.title AS doctitle,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.title) AS foldertitles,
         GROUP_CONCAT(st.title) AS searchtagtitles
    FROM DOCUMENTS d
    JOIN DOCFOLDER df ON df.docid = d.id
    JOIN FOLDERS f ON f.id = dc.folderid
    JOIN DOCSEARCHTAGS dsc ON dsc.docid = d.id
    JOIN SEARCHTAGS st ON st.id = dsc.searchtagid
GROUP BY d.title
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response.  I have tried implementing your solution but am running into some problems...  because there are multiple folders per document, presumably f.title should also be wrapped in a GROUP_CONCAT, however when I do this I get many folder titles repeated in the delimmited resultset...  Any ideas?

Comment: that almost works. However now the delimmited searchtag titles are being repeated...